# How join in this query work?

Tags: oracle, join, common-table-expression

I have a table sales in which I am showing the current quarter average of a product in particular region and that product previous quarter sale. My table has a structure like-

```
Region    Product    Year     Qtr        Month         Sales
NORTH        P1      2015      1          JAN          1000
SOUTH        P1      2015      1          FEB          3000
NORTH        P1      2015      1          MAR          3000
NORTH        P1      2015      2          APR          4000
NORTH        P1      2015      2          MAY          5000
NORTH        P1      2015      2          JUN          6000
NORTH        P1      2015      3          JUL          7000
NORTH        P1      2015      3          AUG          8000
NORTH        P1      2015      3          SEP          9000
NORTH        P1      2015      4          OCT          1000
NORTH        P1      2015      4          NOV          2000
NORTH        P1      2015      4          DEC          4000
........
SOUTH        P3     2015       4          NOV          3000
NORTH        P1     2015       1          FEB          2000
SOUTH        P1     2015       1          JAN          2000
SOUTH        P1     2015       1          JAN          4000
SOUTH        P2     2016       1          JAN          2000
SOUTH        P2     2016       1          JAN          4000
NORTH        P1     2016       1          MAR          3000
NORTH        P1     2016       1          FEB          1000
NORTH        P1     2016       1          JAN          2000
```

and I have ouput in this form-

```
   Region Product Year Month Sales Qtr Avg_Sale  Prev_Qtr_Sale
    NORTH   P1    2015  JAN 1000    1   2000      null
    NORTH   P1    2015  FEB 2000    1   2000      null
    NORTH   P1    2015  MAR 3000    1   2000      null
    NORTH   P1    2015  APR 4000    2   5000      2000
    NORTH   P1    2015  MAY 5000    2   5000      2000
    NORTH   P1    2015  JUN 6000    2   5000      2000
    NORTH    P1   2015  JUL 7000    3   8000      5000
    NORTH   P1    2015  AUG 8000    3   8000      5000
    NORTH   P1    2015  SEP 9000    3   8000      5000
    NORTH   P1    2015  OCT 1000    4   2333.3    8000
    NORTH   P1    2015  NOV 2000    4   2333.3    8000
    NORTH   P1  2015    DEC 4000    4   2333.33   8000
    SOUTH   P2  2015    JAN 8000    1   6000      null
    SOUTH   P2  2015    FEB 9000    1   6000      null
    SOUTH   P2  2015    MAR 1000    1   6000      null
    SOUTH   P2  2015    APR 2000    2   6333.33   6000
    SOUTH   P2  2015    MAY 8000    2   6333.33   6000
    SOUTH   P2  2015    JUN 9000    2   6333.33   6000
    SOUTH   P2  2015    JUL 1000    3   2333.33   6333.33
    SOUTH   P2  2015    AUG 2000    3   2333.33   6333.33
    SOUTH   P2  2015    SEP 4000    3   2333.33   6333.33
    SOUTH   P2  2015    OCT 5000    4   2666.67   2333.33
    SOUTH   P2  2015    NOV 2000    4   2666.67   2333.33
    SOUTH   P2  2015    DEC 1000    4   2666.67   2333.33
    NORTH   P3  2015    FEB 9000    1   5000       null
    NORTH   P3  2015    FEB 1000    1   5000       null
    NORTH   P3  2015    APR 2000    2   2000       5000
    NORTH   P3  2015    JUL 8000    3   8000       2000
    SOUTH   P3  2015    AUG 9000    3   9000       null
    SOUTH   P3  2015    OCT 1000    4   2000       9000
    SOUTH   P3  2015    NOV 3000    4   2000       9000
    NORTH   P1  2016    JAN 2000    1   2000      2333.33
    NORTH   P1  2016    FEB 1000    1   2000      2333.33
    NORTH   P1  2016    MAR 3000    1   2000      2333.33
    SOUTH   P2  2016    JAN 2000    1   3000      2666.67
    SOUTH   P2  2016    JAN 4000    1   3000      2666.67
    SOUTH   P1  2015    JAN 4000    1   3000       null
    SOUTH   P1  2015    JAN 2000    1   3000       null
    SOUTH   P1  2015    FEB 3000    1   3000        null
```

null is showing that there is no sale for that product in previous quarter.
The query is-

```
WITH AvgSales
AS (SELECT
region,
product,
year,
qtr,
ROUND(AVG(sales), 2) AS avg_Sale
FROM sales 
GROUP BY region,
product,
year,qtr
 )
SELECT
s.region,
s.product,
s.year,
s.month,
s.sales,
avg.qtr,
avg.avg_Sale AS Qtr_Avg_Sale,
prev.avg_sale AS Prev_Qtr_Avg_Sale
FROM sales s
JOIN AvgSales avg
ON s.region = avg.region
AND s.product = avg.product
AND s.QTR = avg.qtr
AND s.year = avg.year
LEFT JOIN AvgSales prev
ON  (s.region = prev.region
AND s.product = prev.product
AND s.year - 1 = prev.year
AND prev.qtr = 4) or
(s.region = prev.region
AND s.product = prev.product
AND s.year = prev.year
AND s.qtr - 1 = prev.qtr) ;
```

I have question when joining the table in second join how tables are joining as the join condition why in this join condition it is not including 2,3,4 quarter of previous year

```
s.region = prev.region
    AND s.product = prev.product
    AND s.year - 1 = prev.year
    AND prev.qtr = 4
```

Can anyone can help???

Comment: I want to know why in this join condition it is not including the quarter 2,3,4 of next year as they are also satisfying this condition..:( Why only first quarter runs this?

Comment: To me it looks like there are probably some subsequent calculations (in a report maybe?) that requires the previous year and/or previous quarter (percentage calculations perhaps?). Without more knowledge of how that query is used we can only guess.

Comment: I don't understand what you just said @X.L.Ant

Comment: Without knowing the query requirements, no one can tell why prev.Q4 is always included, and not only for, let's say, Q1. It could be an error in the query, or anything else, as mentioned by @Used_By_Already

Comment: The query as I already told is for calculating the avg of previous quarter only the thing is why its not working when it find qtr 2,3,4 thats mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that the `Prev_Qtr_Sale` column is meant to display average sales for the quarter immediately preceding the quarter of the year in the `Qtr` and `Year` columns - so for `Qtr` 2 of `Year` 2015, the averages for quarter 1 of 2015 should be shown, and so on.

If so, then there is an omission in the first set of conditions left joining to the `prev`-aliased CTE; this set of conditions should be specifically for the special case where `Qtr` is 1 (so joining to the last quarter of the previous year), but the condition `s.qtr = 1` has been omitted.

The full join condition therefore should look like:

```
LEFT JOIN AvgSales prev
ON  (s.region = prev.region
AND s.product = prev.product
AND s.year - 1 = prev.year
AND s.qtr = 1 AND prev.qtr = 4) or
(s.region = prev.region
AND s.product = prev.product
AND s.year = prev.year
AND s.qtr - 1 = prev.qtr)
```